# Update Manager not showing option to upgrade to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, update-manager, 13.04

I am currently running 12.10. I went to the Update Manager and made sure everything was updated. I then reopened it hoping to see the option to upgrade to 13.04. But there was no option. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-manager -d`

Answer (score 2):

It is to be released later today.

On twitter: Getting close now: We might even manage 13.04 at 13:04 BST.

Comment: Twitter just now: Ubuntu 13.04 is LIVE! Download at http://www.ubuntu.com/download . More information and take the tour here: http://www.ubuntu.com/  #Ubuntu1304

Answer (score 2):

It must soon be available.

I don't know why, but some updates-upgrades do not appear as soon as they are released. I suppose there is a location factor concerning repositories.

Answer (score 1):

13.04 has just been released. So, don't worry you would be able to upgrade as soon as the update mirror you are using updates its repositories. Shouldn't take too long for you to enjoy 13.04.

Good luck till then!

Answer (score 0):

There are many [repositories](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) which have to be synchronized with the main repository after it has been released. Unless Canonical synchronizes the repositories before the release, there will be a delay from the announcement to individuals see the release.